# Edge detectors for RGB images?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have implemented Sobel, Prewitt and Canny edge detectors for grayscale images. Do I apply the same operations to each channel for RGB images?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to apply edge detectors to the three color channels (RGB or HSV) independently, and to combine the results using logical operation (output fusion method).

There are also more sophisticated methods, which treat the three channels as coordinates of the 3D color space, and try to find edges by analyzing the gradient (multi-dimensional gradient methods).

[Source1](http://ai.stanford.edu/~ruzon/compass/color.html) [Source2](http://www.dsp.utoronto.ca/~kostas/Publications2008/pub/23.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach of calculating the average of the three channels (It can be weighted as well), and applying edge detection on it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but I expect that you would get better results by transforming into a color space like YUV first.